# How to get timestamp at which a file descriptor monitored by select() becomes ready?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, tcp

My C program uses **TCP socket** for communication.

I am using an iterative server and `select()` to listen for monitoring multiple file descriptors; one TCP socket file descriptor for each client.

Is there a method, using which I can figure out when did a file descriptor become ready?

The application is for a linux platform.

The application is like:

I have a set of file descriptors {fd1, fd2, ... fdN}

```
while (True)
     S <-- select (fd1, fd2, ... fdN)  // Set S contains the ready fds

     S = {fd1, fd2, fd3}.
     /* Say only the file descriptors fd1, fd2 and fd3 are ready.
      * I want to process in FIFO order.
      * Hence, I need timestamp at which a file descriptor became ready.*/

     process (S)   /* It may take 2-3 minutes. Which is not negligible. 
                    * Say t units for generalization.*/
```

Note that in the since it takes *t* units to process the file descriptors, the maximum difference between the *ready time* of two file descriptors in the set **S** can be *t* units.

Hence, the time at which a file descriptor became ready becomes important.

And I want to know how to obtain **the timestamp at which a file descriptor became ready**.

Comment: @LPs What are you talking about? Every accepted connection is returned in the form of a new socket.

Comment: @LPs There are no reason to believe the OP does otherwise -  and it likely has no bearing on the question either way. From the description he's implementing a server with a select() loop in a very standard and straight forward way. accept() creates a file descriptor, you get one for each client.

Comment: @LPs If there is a way of using TCP sockets without `accept()` and `connect()` I have yet to encounter it in 30 years of network programming.

Comment: @EJP my fault.  I'm talking about UDP socket (SOCK_DGRAM).

Comment: Hi all.
Sorry for a late comment.
An example for my problem:

Say file descriptors **fd1** and **fd2** are already ready.
Now I invoke _select()_.
It will return saying **fd1** and **fd2** are ready.
Is there some way to figure out **which file descriptor became ready first**?
Number of file desriptors can be **more than 2**.

Comment: @KulwantSingh Replace the text of your question with the text of that comment.  Then you might have a chance of getting some answers.  It's sad that SO works this way, but this is the way it works.

Comment: *Is there some way to figure out which file descriptor became ready first?*  No.  If it's that important to you, you need to have a separate thread to run `select()` so you can determine which one was first.  Of course, you have to then define what you mean by "first".  What is the **real** problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: For me first according to the clock of my system is sufficient. I understand your point. The clock synchronization problem has been handled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The timestamp at which a file descriptor becomes ready is the modification time of the file descriptor. 
Or in other words, the time at which the file represented by the file descriptor was last modified.

The modification time of a file (represented by a file descriptor) can be obtained using the fstat() method.
Read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fstat.html for details.

Comment: Interesting.  That's technically for a *file*.  A TCP socket is not a file.  That appears to be a non-portable solution.

Comment: in the context of sockets (as requested by OP) this answer is wrong. see my comment [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149061/how-to-get-timestamp-at-which-a-file-descriptor-monitored-by-select-becomes-re#comment58129030_35156404).

Answer (score 3):

As @EJP already explained, select will return a few nanoseconds after the data arrived. Then it is up to you to call gettimeofday() or something equivalent to get the current time.

If you need to avoid the overhead of calling gettimeofday() for each packet, you may give libevent a go cause it supports a cached gettimeofday() (with a little delta depending on how long your packet-handler is running). See http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref3_eventloop.html for more information about event_base_gettimeofday_cached().

If you really need the time of the arrival of the frame with highest possible precision you may switch over to libpcap, DPDK or netmap. They offer the timestamp of the frame arrival - by the drawback that you need to handle the whole IP/TCP-stack (you may use lwip or libnids) on your own.

Comment: Say file descriptors **fd1** and **fd2** are already ready.
Now I invoke _select()_.
It will return saying **fd1** and **fd2** are ready.
Is there some way to figure out **which file descriptor became ready first**?
Number of file desriptors can be **more than 2**.

Comment: why is it so important to get the order? if you run your frame over a network you will see a bunch of devices that _may_ add some (minimal) latency. what is the purpose?

Comment: @ hecke I have added more description to my question. Kindly refer that for relevance.

Comment: @Kulwant - as I'm not able to comment your self accepted answer below:  using fstat() on a socket gives me zeros - for st_[amt]_time. and even if this would work - it would give you the time in seconds. and a second is... ages if you deal with networks. the question above aimed towards to your use case cause maybe you could switch over to another architecture to achieve what you require.

Comment: I just checked the source of Linux 3.16. If a socket is created (net/socket.c), as part of the process a new pseudo Inode is instantiated. After that, inode->i_op is set to sockfs_inode_ops - but this only contains getxattr and listxattr - getattr is not set. But stat (fs/stat.c) requires getattr - or the stats are not updated. This explains why fstat() succeeds on a socket - but it will never deliver any updated stats (at least if you run a Linux kernel).

Answer (score 2):

The socket became ready nanoseconds before `select()` returns. It is ready *now.* `select()` doesn't wait for a bunch of sockets to become ready.

Comment: The first argument of `select` specifies the number of file descriptors you want to wait for. It is the only purpose of `select` to wait for more than one file descriptor. If you want to wait just for one file descriptor, you can use `read`.

Comment: @ceving The first argument of select is the highest number +1 of last file descriptor you want to wait for.

Comment: @ceving `select` waits for *any one* of the file descriptors to become ready; it does not wait for *all* the file descriptors to become ready.  (It *can* report that *more than one* of the fds is ready, if they become ready at very nearly the same time, or if they were already ready before you called `select`.  But, again, it doesn't wait for all of them.  There's no system call to wait for all of N events.)

Comment: @zwol Did I say anything different? Maybe I miss-understood what the asker miss-understood.

Comment: @ceving I think it's me who misunderstood. I thought you were saying that there was no point in calling `select` unless you wanted to wait until *all* of N fds had become ready, which is, of course, not what it does.

Comment: @ceveng The relevance of your comment to my answer escapes me.

Comment: @all I have added more description to the question. Kindly check that.